# google script apps run the next function within the first one

Tags: javascript

I have two functions let's call them function 1  and function 2

I would like in the end of function 1 to start function 2

```
function "function1"() {

  "mycode" 

  run function 2

}
```

I know I could just append the stuff from function 2 in to function 1.
But I would just like to know if this is possible with some simple or easy commadn like "run".

And also because some of my variable in both functions are partly the same so I would have to rewrite/change the code for function 2

So I was just wandering can I just in the end of function 1 start a the function 2 ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do that and It is expected. The main purpose of functions is to reuse the code.You only need to call your function within function 1 like this.

```
function function1() {

  //Code for fucntion 1 
  function2();

}
```

for this case we have an example. You can see it in  [this Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2g9nv/)

```
    function hello(){
        alert("Hello world");
        }

    function salutation(){
        alert("Welcome to our program");
        hello();
    }
    salutation();
```

If the function has many variables defined within the function you can use a function like this

```
    function function1(arg1, arg2,... , argn){
      //code of your function
      function2(arg1, arg2, ... , argk);
}
```

This is the same example one with arguments, you can see it in action [in this JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/muUNV/):

```
function hello(personName){
    alert("Hello world " + personName );
    }

function salutation(personName){
    alert(personName + " welcome to our program");
    hello(personName);
}

salutation("Harold");
```

Comment: as simple as that :) - thanks for all the examples I will try that out and play with the different solutions.